# ruby class.new block not being triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in a Rails initializer:

```
module Mongoid::ActiveRecordBridge
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.belongs_to_record(association_name, options={})
      association_class = (options[:class_name] || association_name.to_s.singularize.classify).constantize
      # index(#{ association_name }_id: 1)
      class_eval <<-EOS
        field :#{ association_name }_id, type: Integer
        def #{ association_name }
          @#{ association_name } ||= #{ association_class }.where(id: #{ association_name }_id).first
        end
        def #{ association_name }=(object)
          @#{ association_name } = object
          self.#{ association_name }_id = object.try :id
        end
      EOS
    end
  end
end

MyCode.all.map do |class_code|
  dynamic_class = "#{class_code.code}_field".classify
  Object.const_set dynamic_class, Class.new do
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::ActiveRecordBridge

    belongs_to_record :classification_code
  end
end
```

It successfully creates the class object, so if class_code was SomeField, then SomeField would be initialized. However, when I run the following it returns false:

```
SomeField.respond_to? :belongs_to_record  => false
```

Yet if I build another object in Rails console, it works fine:

```
2.1.2 :003 > SomeRandomField = Class.new do
2.1.2 :004 >     include Mongoid::Document
2.1.2 :005?>   include Mongoid::ActiveRecordBridge
2.1.2 :006?>   belongs_to_record :classification_code
2.1.2 :007?>   end
 => SomeRandomField 
2.1.2 :008 > SomeRandomField.respond_to? :belongs_to_record
 => true
```

Why when I do it in the initializer, it doesn't work, but in the Rails console it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the block is attached to `Object.const_set`, not `Class.new`

Use something like this:

```
klass = Class.new do
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::ActiveRecordBridge

  belongs_to_record :classification_code
end

Object.const_set dynamic_class, klass
```

Or use parentheses to enforce correct grouping.